# How to get the same <input type="color"> value change functionality across browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, input, colors, cross-browser

I'm working on a web app that uses javascript to do something on the page when a user chooses a color from an `<input type="color">`.

The problem is that `<input type="color">` behaves differently on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari:

- on Safari, when a user clicks `<input type="color">`, **an external colorpicker window does not pop up**
- on Firefox, an external color picker control window pops up, but the `input` element's value only changes when 1) a value change has happened, and 2) when the colorpicker window is then subsequently closed (**EDIT** ...on a Mac; on Windows the user has to click the "OK" button to confirm the value change, not just close the window)

Chrome's behavior is ideal:

- when clicked, the `<input type="color">` provides a colorpicker pop up window
- any time a value is changed inside the colorpicker pop up window, the `input` element's value changes (**before** the colorpicker window is closed)

[Here is a codepen with a vanilla `<input type="color">`](http://codepen.io/bzelip/full/Bpeqya/) that demonstrates this problem when checked on all 3 browsers.

How to use javascript and/or css to get the `<input type="color">` Chrome behavior out of Firefox and Safari?

**EDIT**
The crazy thing about Safari is, [their docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html) that the `color` input type is:

> An input control for specifying a RGB color value. The user can select a color from a color well

Comment: You would have to either create your own replacement color picker, or use a pre-made plugin. There are plenty of plugins available to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid we are not there yet to use this input type in development. Your best solution is to use a cross browser plugin.

You can see the support of the color element at http://caniuse.com/#search=color